# Not visible products are still shown

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, product-list, simple-product

I'm working on a very customised website using magento 1.7.0.2.

I'm creating some configurable products setting simple ones as not visible individually. Unfortunately they are still visible on both list and view page.

I checked product collection object and it seems to me correct as it has visibility 2,4.
Also, I've reindexed and clean the cache.

Do you have an idea about what is going wrong?
thank you

Comment: paste the product collection so we could check please

Comment: I think to have found something interesting about URL rewrites. It seems that the client has done rewrite to the product id like: catalog/product/view/id/70438. Deleting it, the product is not anymore visible. Is this a native magento functionality?

Comment: if that gave the answer please mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

By reading your comment about url rewrite i am going to suggest to truncate the`url_core_rewrite` table from your database. After that do a reindex and see what happens.

Comment: unfortunately it breaks  a lot of links, however is better than work trough backend without mass action